# Angularjs binding not working when called from ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

What am I doing wrong? search() works when called within the controller but not when called through ng-click="search()"

```
$scope.search = () => {
        $scope.getLocation()
            .then(location => xhr('/venues/search', { lat: location.lat, lng: location.lng, category: $scope.category }))
            .then(data => {
            $scope.venues = data;
            $scope.apply();

        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean to write $scope.$apply(), if so, that might be a problem given the fact that ng-click is handled within a $digest loop.

Comment: I tried removing the apply() too, still he same result

Comment: I found out the problem, the ng-click was not declared inside the controller, thanks @Vadim

Answer (score 3):

Please do not put stuff directly on `$scope`. It is considered bad practice, suffers from accidental prototypal member overrides and defeats the purpose of using a class as a Controller.

These are covered in (disclaimer:my) video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E